# How can I disable the new implementation of an activity after when that the touch screen is off?

Tags: android

How can I disable the new implementation of an activity after when that the touch screen is off?

**NOTE: the device is not shut down but also the touch screen is off.**

For example please see the following code and when we click on the `imageView` object, at any time, increases `1` unit to the `textView` object value. If we click ten times on the `imageView` object, the `textView` object will have the `10` values. Now if I do not click on the touch screen, as the result the touch screen will shut down. Now when I want turn on the touch screen the `textView` object value is `0`. While it should have the same `10` value still.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView;
    Integer integer = 0;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(integer.toString());
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                integer = integer + 1;
                textView.setText(integer.toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: can we know that is your problem in this? it is really hard to find your issue

Comment: When the `textView` value is `10` and then when the device sleeps and now when I want see the my activity again, the `textView` value is `0`.

Comment: you need to save your activity state

Comment: in onPause() save the textview value to shared preference and in onResume() assign that value to your textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use onSaveInstanceState to save your state

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView;
    Integer integer = 0;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if (savedInstanceState!=null) {
             integer = savedInstanceState.getInt("count");
        }
        textView.setText(integer.toString());
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                integer = integer + 1;
                textView.setText(integer.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("count", integer);
    }

}
```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState

Comment: from the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

    Note that it is important to save persistent data in onPause() instead of onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) because the later is not part of the lifecycle callbacks, so will not be called in every situation as described in its documentation.

Comment: If it is **Persistent**